# MLlib.DataFrame format for model train

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Most of examples for MLlib.train are using data loaded from libsvm file. However, for my case, I load data from hive and store it in dataframe directly.

I wonder how to organize my dataframe (like generate label part and feature part), to make it used by model directly?  I don't want to store dataframe back to libsvm file for future training, but if it's necessity, also appreciated for how to do that.

Thanks a lot.

============ UPDATE ========

For example, I have a dataframe like below:

---

feature1  | feature2  | feature3 | feature4 |  target

1           1          2           1          1

2           1          3           5          1

1           2          1           1          0

......

I want to treat the last column as target, and other columns as features, then put it to decision tree like below:

```
model = DecisionTree.trainClassifier(df, numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo={},
                                 impurity='gini', maxDepth=5, maxBins=32)
```

How could I define which column to feature or target in "df" here?  Because for most examples, df is loaded from libsvm file as:

```
data = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc, 'data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt')
```

Comment: Please illustrate your question with example data, code and expected output, along with what you have tried yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating an RDD of [LabeledPoints](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#labeled-point). Have a look at this [example](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/mllib-guide.html#linear-regression-1). In this example, parts(0) is your target variable while parts(1) contains a space separated list of features.